# Serving files in ASP.NET 5

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I am trying to use static `html` file from `wwwroot` directory. By default running via `IIS Express` it should display my `html` file that is in `wwwroot` directory but i receive blank page. After doing some investigation i found that server returns error:

[image]

What exactly is needed to get IIS to use static files?

Comment: how are you specifying the path to your html file

Comment: physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by modifying .cs file Configure method to use app.UseFileServer:
[image]